# Is it possible to prove Jensen's inequality via Entropy?

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis, entropy

I am trying to push the mindset that entropy is just a tool to do convexity arguments clearly.

A good milestone would be if one could prove Jensen's inequality (for finite random variables etc.) via entropy.

Of course properties in entropy use Jensen, I don't care about that.

You're allowed to use however powerful tools you want (i.e maybe a proof would need to approximate a convex function with simpler function we can connect to entropy).

Thanks

Comment: I think you can pick up some goods ideas from this [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/167951/entropy-proof-of-brunn-minkowski-inequality).